# Calling functions automatically in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

My main program reads the configuration file and the configuration file tells it which functions to run. The functions are in a separate file, currently when ever i create a new function i have to add the function call in the main program (so it can be evoked when the it is indicated by the configuration file)

My question is, is there any way i can leave the main program alone, and when i add a new function, it can be called through some kind of array.

example (bear me, i am not so sure you can do this).

I have an array (or enum),

```
char functions [3] = ["hello()","run()","find()"];
```

when i read the config file and it says run hello(), can i run it using the array (i can find if the test exist in the array)

also i can easily add new functions to the array.

Note: i know it can not be done with an array, so just an example

Answer (score 5):

Something like this i think.

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void hello()
{
   std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

void what()
{
   std::cout << "What" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> functions = 
   {
      std::make_pair("hello", hello),
      std::make_pair("what", what)
   };
   functions["hello"]();
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/49685630531cd6284de6eed9b10e0870

Comment: is it possible to make it a void * function, and takes in data, so void *hello(void *data)

Comment: @Rave Yeah and all your functions should have the same prototype. std::function<void(void*)>.

Comment: all of my functions take in void * and return void *, since i made them to be used as thread functions. i tried doing std::function<(void *)(void*)>, i am getting errors

Comment: @Rave what is your compiler? it`s C++11 standard. Also you can use boost::function, and of course map with key string and value pointer to function.

Comment: I am using g++, i will try boost

Comment: @Rave gcc 4.5+ has std::function class for example.

Comment: `std::function` in this senario is really bad advice. Function pointers are the way to go

Answer (score 4):

Expose from your main a function that can register new tuples `{ function_name, function_pointer}` in a map (as proposed by the other answers).

Typically:

```
// main.h
typedef void (*my_function)(void *);
int register_function(const std::string &name, my_function function);

// main.c
int register_function(const std::string &name, my_function function)
{
  static std::map<std::string, my_function> s_functions;
  s_functions[name] = function;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  for( std::map<std::string, my_function>::const_iterator i=s_functions.begin();
       i != s_functions.end();
       ++i)
  {
    if( i->second )
    {
      // excecute each function that was registered
      (my_function)(i->second)(NULL);
    }
  }

  // another possibility: execute only the one you know the name of:
  std::string function_name = "hello";
  std::map<std::string, my_function>::const_iterator found = s_functions.find(function_name);
  if( found != s_functions.end() )
  {
    // found the function we have to run, do it
    (my_function)(found->second)(NULL);
  }
}
```

Now, in each of your auther source files, that implement the functions to run, do this:

```
// hello.c
#include "main.h"

void my_hello_function(void *)
{
  // your code
}

static int s_hello = register_function("hello", &my_hello);
```

This means that everytime you add a new source file with this kind of statements, it will automatically be added to the list of functions you have available to execute.

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems the best implementation for me now

Comment: I get my_function, is not declared, in the main.c.
static std::map<std::string, my_function> s_functions; i included the header and i am using g++

Comment: Yes, this was a typo in my `main.h` file. Should read: `typedef void (*my_function)(void *);` (I misplaced the first `*`)

Answer (score 3):

Use pointer to functions to do it.

For example(I'm not sure in syntax):

```
map<string,void(*)()> funcs;
```

and then do `funcs[name]();`

Comment: You're almost there. void(*)() is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/intro.html#what) (also called "functors"). Instead of calling a specific function, you can conditionally call a reference to one of various functions of your choice. The tutorials [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) provide a well-documented introduction to the subject.