# how to correctly apply std::map

Tags: c++, function, mapping

I've read that std::map is often used to map function's pointers but i don't really understand how it works, here is the code where i would use that:

```
// here go all the functions to call

int main() {

    std::array<bool, 4> exercises;
    int chosenExercise;

    exercises.fill(false);

    do {
        std::cout << "Type the exercise's number you want to look at or type 0 to leave'.\n" << "(Available exercises go from 1 to " << exercises.size() << ".) \n";
        std::cin >> chosenExercise;

        if (chosenExercise < 0 || chosenExercise > exercises.size()) {
            std::cout << "Error.\n\n";
        }
    } while (chosenExercise < 0 || chosenExercise > exercises.size());

    if (chosenExercise == 0) {
        std::cout << "Leaving...";
    }
    else {
        exercises.at(chosenExercise - 1) = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < exercises.size(); i++) {
            if (exercises.at(i) == true) {
                // call the selected exercise's function and run it
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause>0");
}
```

inside the last **if** the program should find which exercise was chosen and call its function.
Does anybody know how it would apply to this case?

Comment: No, `std::map` doesn't call any functions automatically, or are you talking about the comparisn operators for the key value types?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i'm talking about what they said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535124/calling-functions-automatically-in-c-c , i'm not understanding how any of this works

Comment: That's a map of function pointers, yes (look up these 1st to understand). That doesn't mean that `std::map` calls those functions _"automatically"_. You have to do the call.

Comment: @newbie the calling of the function has little to do with the map, it just uses `std::function`, something unrelated to `std::map` to run the function. Consider looking up the documentation/examples for both `std::map` and `std::function`. Best to not try blindly experimenting with things when you yourself admit you have no idea how they work, I say :\

Comment: @newbie Maybe this helps: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+map+menu+choice+function+pointer&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&biw=1600&bih=789&sxsrf=ALeKk03FNXtP3vxALz6V6_sdrAt0ayyaKw%3A1619369795536&ei=Q5-FYOuJIL2L9u8PtZWs2AE&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+map+menu+choice+function+pointer&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQmMFbWPO9XGCowFxoAXACeACAAZcCiAGGKJIBBjUzLjUuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwirt7DL7pnwAhW9hf0HHbUKCxsQ4dUDCA4&uact=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I recommend a quick recap on [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Now, maps have a key and a value. By `std::map::operator[]` or `std::map::at()`, you enter a key and a reference to the value is returned. In your case, the key is something like `std::string` and the value is an `std::function` pointing to whatever function you want. Now, consider this example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

void sayHello() { std::cout << "Hello!\n"; }
void sayBye()   { std::cout << "Bye!\n";   }

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> funcs = {
        {"hello", sayHello},
        {"bye", sayBye}
    };
    std::string inpFunc;
    std::cout << "What do you want me to say? ";
    std::cin >> inpFunc;
    try
    {
        funcs.at(inpFunc)();
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range &)
    {
        std::cout << "I don't know how to say that!\n";
    }
}
```

This is a basic example of what you are trying to do. In our map, we have two key/value pairs: `{"hello", sayHello}` and `{"bye", sayBye}`. Hopefully, you get this much. If not, perhaps try taking another look at how `std::map` works.

Now, we get the input of a string which should be one of the keys in our map. Looking inside the `try` block:

```cpp
funcs.at(inpFunc)();
```

Perhaps this is easier to understand as `(funcs.at(inpFunc))()`. With `funcs.at(inpFunc)`, we get a reference to the value with the key we pass into `at`. If this was `"hello"`, it would return `sayHello`, for example. Now, [the `()` after that is simply an overload of `std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()) that calls the function it holds. That's pretty much it. I put a `try ... catch` too just so that if the key doesn't exist, it handles the situation.

---

A few examples of running this program:

```
What do you want me to say? hello
Hello!
```

```
What do you want me to say? bye
Bye!
```

```
What do you want me to say? hey
I don't know how to say that!
```

Comment: I took a look at std::function and std::map as you said and kinda understood, but your example made it very clear, appreciate it!